# How to get C-style functions from source file?

Tags: regex, parsing, lexer

I need to read source file and find all c/c++ functions and get them for further proccessing. Tried it with PHP and regexp

```
$patt = '/([a-z ]*?)(\w+?)\s*(\(.*?\))\s*(\{.*\})/s';
```

But looks like its wrong way. What is the best way to do it?

Here's the example of function that i need to get:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int a=11112,baa=3,c;
   int a[] ={1,32,3,4,535,35,3,114};
   c=a+b;
}
```

As you can see `114};` that curve ruins regexp. So I think there's a better solution.

Comment: it works https://regex101.com/r/hE9iF2/3

Comment: If you want to parse source files reliably, take a look at antlr, flex, bison, ragel.

Comment: It will work incorrectly if there are few or more functions in source file.

Comment: In general case `regex` is too weak. You have to fully parse the `c/c++ string`.

Comment: Looks like that tools are pretty complex to use, huh? I would like to have a simplier solution for starters.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is also complex

Comment: If you know the function's closing brace will be at the start of a line, try inserting `\n` before the `\}` in your regex.

Comment: Nice idead about inserting \n before \}. Also I'll try to take a look at antlr, flex and other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

There have been many hints in the comments that it cannot be done using regular expression matching and must be done by parsing using more powerful tools, but have not really explained why this is so, or even why parsing is different from regular expression matching. It might leave the reader with the impression that if one worked **really hard** that you might be able to do it or if you were **really clever** enough you could do it too. This is not true but needs a detailed explanation to really understand why.

It is an element of a good computer science education to understand problems like this, to such a degree that questions like yours are often set as examination questions to enable a student's understanding of the theory as applied to programming problems to be demonstrated. The weak student will try and write the regular expression and the strong student will demonstrate why it is impossible.

Such questions also show why just being a good and experienced programmer is not good enough. Irrespective of how many years of programming and computer experience someone has, without encountering the theory, this remains an insoluble problem. It is also my lament that some modern computer science degree courses, which focus on practical tasks, such as the creation of apps and modern platforms, often omit this critical element.

## Background

So to the theory. We cite the work of [Noam Chomsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky) and his [Language Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). This outlines different levels of language specification mechanisms (Grammars) and distinguishes between their capabilities. The simplest form of grammar would be called Chomsky type-3, which represented a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), which we use as [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

A regular expression, irrespective of implementation or notation, has the ability to specify repeated sequences of symbols. Anything that is formed by patterns of repeating symbols can be matched by a regular expression.

We can match sequences of `a`, `b` and `c`s, such as(+):

```
(a|b|c)*              --- any number of a,b,c's in any order
a*b*c*                --- any number of a,b,c's in order
(abc|cba|bac|cab)*    --- any number of a,b,c's in equal number
```

However, one thing we cannot do is write a pattern for equal number of a,b,c's in a specific order, such as:

```
aabbcc, aaabbbccc
```

This also works for symbols like brackets:

```
[[bb]], {{{bbb}}}, ((((bbbb))))
```

What regular grammars cannot do is specify correct nesting. A more powerful mechanism is needed for that. The more powerful mechanism is known as Chomsky type-2 language, or [context free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). (*) We normally experience these as the *rules of grammar* in some notation such as [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) or similar. We can handle nesting like this:

```
exp -> ( exp ) | id
id  -> a | b | c
```

This then gives us the equal numbers of open and close brackets we desire.

## The Question

So, lets get back to the original question. How can we match **C**/C++ functions? If the language only allowed functions to look like this:

```
type name (type1 parameter1, type2 parameter2, ...) {
 ... body ...
 }
```

Your regular expression would do it, but as you noticed, there are structures inside a function that can contain pairs of `{}` that require something can handle nesting. Sometimes at this point some programmers think they can write code to count the number of open `{` and close `}` and avoid the need for grammars and parsers. However, it does not take many examples to show the flaws in this approach. Consider:

```
my function (an arg) { /* } */ arg = "{"; outch('{'); /* } */ }
```

Which shows not all symbols will be nested equally.

As a consequence, to identify functions in a language like **C**/C++, one has to almost fully parse (process) almost all the structures of the language using a set of rules for most of the language. To do this usually requires using a parser generator tools, such as suggested in the comments. Bison, yacc, antlr and so on, are examples of such tools.

## Summary

In explaining why this is a question identifying a particularly special problem in computer science, I hope that over questioners and novice programmers would avoid the similar mistake and be lead to the correct knowledge that will enable their problem to be solved. Even better, it might lead some to update their knowledge of this important area of computer technology.

---

[+] I'm just typing this live, from my memory, and not from a text-book. If I err at the nature or detail of the example I apologise. My favourite book for examples and explanations of this material is: [Cleaveland, J.C & Uzgalis, R.C. (1976) *Grammars for Programming Languages*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444001875). If you have one, you are a lucky person.
(*) For those who know the pedandic difference between a grammar and the language it generates, I apologise at by blurring of terminology.